# android action mode close icon / button on honeycomb

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to change the icon for the action mode close button. This works fine in JB,

```
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_cab_close</item>
```

but in Honeycomb, it has no effect. there, I see the green-style button overlay and and icon that is not the one I specified.

[image]

as a test, i've also tried this,

```
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionModeCloseButton</item>
    ...
    <style name="ActionModeCloseButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
         <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

which has no effect on Honeycomb, but does work as expected on JB.

any ideas?